# Derivation of the Poisson equation for weak gravitational lensing

Tags: mathematical-physics, mathematics, gravitational-lensing, weak-lensing

In my BSc project we studied the derivation of deflection potential for a weak lensing system, which is $$\psi(\vec{\theta})=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{R^2}d^2\theta' \kappa(\vec{\theta'})\ln{|\vec{\theta}-\vec{\theta'}|}.$$Now my goal is to derive a lensing equivalent of the Poisson equation, which is $$\nabla^2\psi=2\kappa.$$ I was told that the derivation requires the use of the Green's functions, but it seems that I have done it without the use of the Green's functions and would like you tell me if there is any flaw in my derivation method. I began by taking the Laplacian of the deflection potential: $$\nabla^2\psi(\vec{\theta})=\nabla^2\Big(\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{R^2}d^2\theta' \kappa(\vec{\theta'})\ln{|\vec{\theta}-\vec{\theta'}|}\Big)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{R^2}d^2\theta' \kappa(\vec{\theta'})\nabla^2\ln{|\vec{\theta}-\vec{\theta'}|},$$ where we can take the nabla into the integral because it is acting on $\theta$, not $\theta'$. We know that $$\nabla^2\ln{|\vec{\theta}|}=2\pi\delta(\vec{\theta}),$$ so we get $$\nabla^2\psi(\vec{\theta})=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{R^2}d^2\theta' \kappa(\vec{\theta'})(2\pi\delta(\vec{\theta}-\vec{\theta'}))=2\int_{R^2}d^2\theta' \kappa(\vec{\theta'})\delta(\vec{\theta}-\vec{\theta'}).$$ We also know that $$\int_a^bf(x)\delta(x-\alpha)dx=f(\alpha),$$ so $$\nabla^2\psi(\vec{\theta})=2\kappa.$$

Is there anything wrong with this calculations?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your derivation. By the way $\ln\rho$, with $\rho^2=x^2+y^2$,  is the Green's function of the Laplace operator in 2D, so "using the Green's functions" might boil down to understanding why $\nabla^2\ln{|\vec{\theta}|}=2\pi\delta(\vec{\theta})$ as you wrote.

Comment: As far as I know, there is a "method of Green's function", but it is useful to solve the inverse problem, i.e. finding the solution of the equation $\nabla^2\psi=2\kappa$ when $\kappa(\theta)$ is a given function.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. As long as my derivation isn't flawed then I'm happy. I think you're correct about the use of Green's functions boiling down to understanding the identity.